# Consume Swagger definition to generate c# client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, api, swagger

I'm trying to consume the Swagger sample Petstore definition .json file at -
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json

I used VS 2017 > Add > Add REST Api Client functionality. The import is successful and the Swagger Petstore proxy classes are successfully generated and added to my project.

[image]

Now I want to write C# code that is actually able to call the Petstore API.I'm unable to find any concrete examples that leverage the **proxy classes above**.

The way I have worked with REST services has been using the Web Client class in C# -

```
string sendText = "abc";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
result = c.UploadString(url, sendText);
```

How do I write code that calls the PUT GET POST etc. operation on the Pet Store API?

Comment: You can use the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient) class.

Comment: Visual Studio uses [AutoRest](https://dzimchuk.net/generating-clients-for-your-apis-with-autorest/) under the covers for the proxy classes. You should instantiate an instance of `SwaggerPetstore` and call the methods available to GET, PUT, POST, etc.

Comment: Look into the swagger-codegen https://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/ you can use it to generate clients in multiple languages based on the swagger json model. Also available at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started